# ID token is cleared during storage to session

Tags: pac4j

We use `play-pac4j` in [CiviForm](https://civiform.us/), an open-source, public interest project. I am working on providing logout support for OIDC (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/civiform/civiform/issues/4359)).

As suggested in [Getting ID Token for Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75693656/1623584), I am revising our code to store an instance of a custom subclass of `OidcProfile` in the session. However, one aspect of the default handling puzzles me: when the callback is processed, the profile is [scrubbed](https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j/blob/7f39aab4da3e7649d95947b9cd14ac6f14fe535b/shared/src/main/java/org/pac4j/play/store/PlayCookieSessionStore.java#L148) in such a way that the `id_token` is [removed from the profile](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/eef713772246303327f9239631726a0bb48afef4/pac4j-oidc/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oidc/profile/OidcProfile.java#L261) before it is stored in the session. This puts me back at square one: the `id_token` is not available in the profile to be populated in the logout request.

I can get around this by overriding [`removeLoginData()`](https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j/blob/eef713772246303327f9239631726a0bb48afef4/pac4j-oidc/src/main/java/org/pac4j/oidc/profile/OidcProfile.java#L260-L264) in my custom subclass of `OidcProfile` such that it does not remove the `id_token`. Is that a bad idea? I'm a little wary of doing this without understanding why the `id_token` is being removed in the base implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID token (like the access token) is removed from the OIDC profile because of the storage you pick: `PlayCookieSessionStore`.

The size of the cookie is limited so this is necessary to limit the size of the profile.

Use the `PlayCacheSessionStore` to be able to store the whole profile: https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j/wiki/Security-configuration#2-choose-the-right-sessionstore